# Find a dropzone to change attributes

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, dropzone.js

I'm having some problems with the Dropzone.js. After I create a dropzone I want to change its values (for example the url) before sending the form via POST.
I already set the variable autoProcessQueue to false, so I can send the files when the form is sent.
Here is a test that I made but is not working...

```
var myDropzone = new Dropzone(me, { 
                url:  uploadUrl
                ,maxFilesize: 10
                ,addRemoveLinks: true
                ,addDownloadLinks: true
                ,downloadFileUrl: downloadUrl
                ,autoProcessQueue: false      
                ,init: function() {
                    var myDrop = this;

                    $("[id=btnSendMessage]").click(function(e){ 
                      //  e.preventDefault();
                        url2 = '/file/upload/52175';
                        myDrop.url = url2;
                        myDrop.processQueue();
                    });

                }
```

So, how can I change the url ? I dont know what to do here.

Thank you! :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is a [page](https://github.com/enyo/dropzone/wiki/Set-URL-dynamically) on the dropzone wiki that shows you how to do this. I'm typing it out here for posterity. You can take advantage of the `processingfile` event to set the upload url.

```
<form id="my-dropzone" action="/some-url" class="dropzone"></form>
<script>
Dropzone.options.myDropzone = {
  init: function() {
    this.on("processing", function(file) {
      this.options.url = "/some-other-url";
    });
  }
};
</script>
```